# foreach loop for creating a HTML markup from a PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Imagine you have an array of HTML elements (in their appearance order) as

```
$array = array(
  1=>array( 'level' => 1, 'element' => '<div class="parent">'),
  2=>array( 'level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">'),
  3=>array( 'level' => 3, 'element' => '<span class="child2">'),
  4=>array( 'level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">'),
  5=>array( 'level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">'),
  6=>array( 'level' => 3, 'element' => '<span class="child2">'),
  7=>array( 'level' => 4, 'element' => '<span class="child3">'),
);
```

How do you plan a `foreach` loop to find the places of the closing HTML tags to output a string as

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <span class="child2">
        <span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <span class="child2">
            <span class="child3">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My attempt was something like

```
foreach($array as $e){

echo $e['element'];

$level = $e['level'];
    if($level<=$previous_level) {
    echo $closing; 
    $closing = '';
    }
$closing.= '</'. $element . '>'; // which comes from parsed $e['element'];

$previous_level = $level;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar I tried to store the closing tag in a string/array when looping, but couldn't release the stored closings tag at the right time.

Comment: So ... show us some code.

Comment: @Marcel I added a simplified code for your reference.

Comment: Why don't you order them as a tree and go recursive about it ? Way easier

Comment: @PommeDeTerre since the level of depth is unknown, I think it will be more complicated to do so.

Comment: The level of depth does not really matter in this case. What you are having as data is an unstructured tree of elements. When finishing processing an element you have to close it. Between these operations you have to perform the exact same logic in the children. That is a tree and what is easier is recursive to my opinion. Recursive will be more intuitive, you can make it flat after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with stack,

```
$array = array(
    1=>array( 'level' => 1, 'element' => '<div class="parent">'),
    2=>array( 'level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">'),
    3=>array( 'level' => 3, 'element' => '<span class="child2">'),
    4=>array( 'level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">'),
    5=>array( 'level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">'),
    6=>array( 'level' => 3, 'element' => '<span class="child2">'),
    7=>array( 'level' => 4, 'element' => '<span class="child3">'),
);

$result = "";
$tags = [];    // stack to store node end tag
$levels = [];  // stack to store node level
foreach($array as $tag){

    $level = $tag["level"];
    $element = $tag["element"];

    while(end($levels) >= $level){ // pop all Sibling and their child
        array_pop($levels);
        $result .= array_pop($tags);
    }

    $result .= str_pad("",$level-1,"\t") . $element . "\n";
    array_push($tags, str_pad("",$level-1,"\t") . "</" .substr($element,1,strpos($element," ")-1) . ">\n");
    array_push($levels,$level);
}
while(end($levels)){
    array_pop($levels);
    $result .= array_pop($tags);
}
echo $result;
```

And the result,

```
php test.php
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
                <span class="child2">
                </span>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
        </div>
        <div class="child">
                <span class="child2">
                        <span class="child3">
                        </span>
                </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution using recursive function:

```
$array = array(
    1 => array('level' => 1, 'element' => '<div class="parent">', 'parsedElement' => 'div'),
    2 => array('level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">', 'parsedElement' => 'div'),
    3 => array('level' => 3, 'element' => '<span class="child2">', 'parsedElement' => 'span'),
    4 => array('level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">', 'parsedElement' => 'div'),
    5 => array('level' => 2, 'element' => '<div class="child">', 'parsedElement' => 'div'),
    6 => array('level' => 3, 'element' => '<span class="child2">', 'parsedElement' => 'span'),
    7 => array('level' => 4, 'element' => '<span class="child3">', 'parsedElement' => 'span'),
);

function displayTree(&$tree, $level = 1) {
    if (!$tree) {
        return;
    }
    $el = array_shift($tree); // get the current element
    echo $el['element'];
    if ($tree && $tree[0]['level'] > $level) {
        // if the next item is a child of this then increase the level and process the sub-tree
        displayTree($tree, $level+1);
    }
    echo '</'. $el['parsedElement'] . '>';
    if ($tree && $tree[0]['level'] < $level) {
        return; // go back to the parent
    }
    displayTree($tree, $el['level']); // process the next sibling
}
displayTree($array);
```

Output:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <span class="child2"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child">
        <span class="child2">
            <span class="child3"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```